# Modify specific JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

```
<html>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">var ajax_array = {"type":"all_users","kind":"users"};</script>

  <div class="modal users-list">
    <div class="list">
        <script type="text/javascript">var ajax_array = {"type":"all_users","kind":"users"};</script>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to modify the array of ajax_array variable that inside the modal `.users-list` not that exists directly in `<body>` tag.

My question how can search for variables that I need to modify? I know only that if I need to modify a variable making something like this directly `ajax_array.kind = 'posts'` but this will modify all variables that have `ajax_array` name.

Comment: There's only _one_ `ajax_array` in your code as they are defined at global scope.
The second `var ajax_array` is simply overriding the first ones.

Comment: Why is jQuery tagged here? And why do both of these have the same name? `var` uses global scope. You are not making two elements

Comment: Read this in its entirety: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` sets the scope of the variable either to the function it is declared within or, if it is not declared in a function, to global scope (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)). This means that if I declare a variable using `var` in one script block, then that variable will be accessible in another script block:

```html
<script>
    var foo = "bar";
</script>
<script>
    console.log(foo); // logs "bar" to the console
</script>
```

If you want the variable to be scoped to your script tag, then you can use `let` coupled with a block (`{` and `}`), which declares variables with a much more restricted scope (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)):

```html
<script>
{
    // foo is only defined within the opening and closing curly braces
    let foo = "bar";
}
</script>
<script>
    console.log(foo); // error: foo is not defined
</script>
```

So, if you want to reuse the same variable name in two script tags, you can use the following:

```
<script>
{
    let foo = "bar1";
}
</script>
<script>
{
    // this is a different foo... changing it will not affect the first one
    let foo = "bar2";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because they are in global scope. Wrap them in an IIFE, so that they will not be overridden outside that scope:

```
(function(){
// your code here...
// now, if you override ajax_array.kind = 'posts'
// this will only override inside this scope
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to just use another variable name. In javascript `var` is not strictly block scoped so when you call `ajax_array` you are only rewriting or modifying your first call.

```
<html>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">var ajax_array = {"type":"all_users","kind":"users"};</script>
  <div class="modal users-list">
    <div class="list">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var foo = {"type":"all_users","kind":"users"}; // Initialize to the same value
          // Do whatever to foo
        </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this suggestion, assigning `foo` a reference to `ajax_array`, will still produce the undesired behavior of attaching a property to "both" objects (technically there was only ever one). The OP seems to want separate objects.

Comment: @JDB you are correct, I forgot that objects are references. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

why do you even want to do it like this? A better way may be to  use input type hidden and then get the values of that hidden input type. And if you have to do it like this change variable name. Var is global scoped variable which will be created in window scope (global object). Its a key, value pair so can only contain one value for one key